# Crm 2011 Entity Collection Querying and Performance Issues

Tags: c#, optimization, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have an application that needs to query some entities and get the one that matches a criteria. This was the first thing that was done. It needs to be called a many times over and over with different criteriaValues, which is bad, as the round trip time is degrading performance seriously.

```
private AnEntity GetEntity(string criteriaValue, IOrganizationService service)
{
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
    query.EntityName = "entityname";
    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "desiredField1", "desiredField2" });
    query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
    query.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
    query.Criteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("criteriaField", ConditionOperator.Equal, criteriaValue));
    EntityCollection entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    if (entities.Entities.Count > 0)
    {
        return (AnEntity)entities[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now I'm considering Retrieving all the entities once when the application starts, and use LINQ queries on the EntityCollection, something like this.

```
private AnEntity GetEntity(string criteriaValue, EntityCollection theEntityCollection)
{
    var desiredEntity = from e in theEntityCollection.Entities
    where e.criteriaField.Equals(criteriaValue)
    select e;
    return (AnEntity)desiredEntity;
}
```

Are there any better alternatives to this approach? Like maybe retrieving everything, storing them in a HashTable/Dictionary and using criteriaValue as the key? I'd love to hear any suggestions.

Thank you very much in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do, since you are only returning a single record, is to put a  count of 1 on it.  By default CRM will return the first 5000 records that match the count.

Here is the code to specify that you only want to return the first item:

```
query.PageInfo.Count = 1; // Number of records to return
query.PageInfo.PageNumber = 1; // Page count.
```

If that doesn't improve performance to an acceptable level, retrieving all of the entities and storing them as a Dictionary is also a valid method.  Just remember that the data could get stale...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the overall number of records verses how many match your criteria overall. If you have say 100,000 records and only 1000 match your criteria then I would say to stick with your current approach. If however most of your records will be matched then its worth bringing them all back in one go and then splitting them out.

One thing you can do and is supported in CRM is to add indexes to the underlying tables in the SQL database. This would speed things up if you have lots of records in the table so well worth giving that a go.